# HTMLCanvasElement has no method 'toDataUrl'

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, data-url

I am trying to fetch the dataUrl from the canvas to use is as css background-image on various elements.
But i always get following error `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLCanvasElement> has no method 'toDataUrl'`

this is my test code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
  alert(c.toDataUrl());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

is it once again the security feature in disguise?, or am i simply stupid...

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can find the Mozilla Documentation Network pages for stuff like this with a google search for "MDN toDataUrl" - google is case-insensitive.

Comment: Read the docs. Any docs. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-canvas-element.html#dom-canvas-todataurl

Comment: this is what happens when you code for 20 hours straight

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have the function name incorrect. Watch the case:

```
alert(c.toDataURL());
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a9mgx/)